# The minimum amount of letters that can have an atlas of an sphere is 2 or 6?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have a doubt about if the minimum amount of letters (or maps) to cover a sphere is 2 or 6.
My answer is 2 but I'm not sure. I gave the following parametrizations:

$$\rho_{1}:(0,2\pi)\times(0,\pi)\to S ~\textrm{such that}~ \rho_{1}(u,v)=(\cos{u}\sin{v},\sin{u}\sin{v},\cos{v})$$
and
$$\rho_{2}:(-\pi,\pi)\times(0,\pi)\to S ~\textrm{such that}~ \rho_{2}(u,v)=(\cos{u}\sin{v},\cos{v},\sin{u}\sin{v})$$
Obviously $\rho_{1}$ covers all the sphere except the half of circumference over the plane $xOz$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\rho_{2}$ covers all the sphere except the half of circumference over the plane $xOy$ for $x\leq 0$. That's why I say that the answer is two.

However in the notes of a professor I saw that he put a case analogous for an ellipsoid and said that it was 6.

Comment: @coffeemath No, they are not circles. They are half of circles and they don,t meet

Comment: I am fairly new to differential geometry as well, but I believe (?) we need only two charts, as we can use the north pole projection
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
\vdots \\
x^{n}
\end{bmatrix} =\frac{1}{1-x^{n}}\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
\vdots \\
x^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
And also the south pole
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
\vdots \\
x^{n}
\end{bmatrix} =\frac{1}{1+x^{n}}\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
\vdots \\
x^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
We use both of these so that we don't miss either of $[0 ~\cdots~1]^\mathrm{T}$ or $[0 ~\cdots~-1]^\mathrm{T}$

Comment: @K.defaoite yes, it seems it also works